# How to make MSBuild15 to restore all projects in the folders other than 'src, test'

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I'm trying to restore packages for ASP.NET Core project using `dotnet msbuild` command.

I know `dotnet msbuild` command is just an alias for MSBuild(v15), but I think `dotnet` CLI is proper than using MSBuild directly.

Anyway, my solution structure is like this:

- [src]
- [test]
- [samples]
- MyProject.sln

When I restore the solution by using `dotnet msbuild /t:Restore` on the root directory of the solution, it doesn't restore projects in the [samples] directory.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets#restore-target) documentation that seems to be related, but I couldn't figure out how to restore custom folders.

Of course, I can make explicit command like `dotnet msbuild /t:Restore {path-to-the-project}`, but I believe there's better way to achieve it.

How to restore all projects in several folders at once using MSBuild?

P.S.

I miss project.json and global.json :(

**[Added]**
I found something different between usual projects and sample projects like this:

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Storage", "src\Storage\Storage.csproj", "{E2AAC236-D77A-4EE0-9219-641A1BA51E4A}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Storage.Tests", "test\Storage.Tests\Storage.Tests.csproj", "{B944D0A7-22E4-4C22-889A-986D592EEA67}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SampleApp", "samples\SampleApp\SampleApp.csproj", "{5CC90F0F-C757-4A92-A4D1-6069F1AB1D01}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {795681B9-4282-49FF-BE16-BB3957D88E58} = {795681B9-4282-49FF-BE16-BB3957D88E58}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

All other projects in the src/test folder doesn't have any child elements in the `.sln` file. But only projects in the sample folder has child element `PostSection(ProjectDependencies)`.

I have no idea what that means, but it doesn't look like a cause of the problem.

Comment: Are the [samples] projects in your `MyProject.sln`?  `dotnet msbuild` sees that you have a solution file in your folder, and it restores for all projects in that solution.

Comment: @EricErhardt yes, `MyProject.sln` contains all projects in the sample folder. But I found something different, I will add details in the question.